# file access in winrt apps media player library

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, file-permissions

I am new to WinRT and I was planning on developing a WinRT app for a simple media player that would play audio/video, create playlist and have media library.

As I was thinking I would make a playlist class and serialize it when a playlist is saved. This playlist class would be holding path to the audio/video files that could be anywhere in the hard disk. Similarly for library I would store files info and path in the database for future access in the database. But as it turned out I can only access other files on system using pickers (except for few files).

But as we know that there is library and playlist features in the winrt music app in win8, there must be a legal and efficient way to do so.

Comment: Have you tried the folder picker? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx. You can scan within the folder chosen by the user. Otherwise, your app is limited to known places like the music folder.

Comment: @WiredPrairie thanks for response.. but this is not what i want. I don't wan't users to use pickers everytime they wanna play a song.. this is not how my playlist and library class would work

Comment: You'd just prompt once. You have to save the tokens for files, folders, etc. so that they can be accessed again. Or, it has to be from a standard location (like the Music Library). This is what the Windows Music app does in Windows 8 as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i wanted... i 'll start working on it right away. I'll let you know if i things didn't work out